# Convert function PHP to C#

Tags: c#, php, code-conversion

I am stuck in a convertion of PHP function to C#!

Someone can tell me what I am doing bad?

Original code (PHP):

```
function delete_all_between($beginning, $end, $string)
{
    $beginningPos = strpos($string, $beginning);
    $endPos = strpos($string, $end);
    if ($beginningPos === false || $endPos === false) {
        return $string;
    }

    $textToDelete = substr($string, $beginningPos, ($endPos + strlen($end)) - $beginningPos);

    return str_replace($textToDelete, '', $string);
}
```

My code C#:

```
string delete_all_between(string beginning, string end, string html)
{
    int beginningPos = html.IndexOf(beginning);
    int endPos = html.IndexOf(end);
    if (beginningPos == -1 || endPos == -1)
    {
        return html;
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me, I am really stuck!

Comment: What exactly is your problem here? DOes it compile? Do you get errors? Any unexpected results?

Comment: What's happening that's incorrect? I noticed you're missing the last two lines of code from your PHP function in your C# code. Also, I'll just throw it out there that `end` is a reserved word in C#. Try rename your end variable to something else.

Comment: Please read  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question . We need a clear problem statement (also see [mcve] for guidance).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the following and edit your question appropriately:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

Use `Substring` and `Replace` to mask out and replace the unwanted string. Also, I would add a check to make sure that `endPos > beginningPos`:

```
string delete_all_between(string beginningstring, string endstring, string html)
{
    int beginningPos = html.IndexOf(beginningstring);
    int endPos = html.IndexOf(endstring);
    if (beginningPos != -1 && endPos != -1 && endPos > beginningPos) 
    {
        string textToDelete = html.Substring(beginningPos, (endPos - beginningPos) + endstring.Length); //mask out
        string newHtml = html.Replace(textToDelete, ""); //replace mask with empty string
        return newHtml; //return result
    }
    else return html; 
}
```

**Test with input**

```
delete_all_between("hello", "bye", "Some text hello remove this byethat I wrote")
```

Yields the result:

> Some text that I wrote

Comment: OP seems to want to return original input unaltered if the validation on the indexes fail.

Comment: @Andrew Updated it! Thanks!